# Browser back button lost session on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm clicking browser back button and then I try to go to any aspx page,  I'm losting session on my Asp.net web project. 
How can I solve this?

My master page load code like that;

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            if (Session["admin_id"] != null)
            {
                AdminName.Text = Session["admin_name"].ToString();
                mybadge.Text = Session["my_badge"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not touching/saving any data before navigating to another page. So that's why session gets blank when you press on back button.

Comment: No because session is saving all pages. But this problem for just back button.